# using key presses instead of buttons in django forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I have a website that allows text entry, voting on entries, and live tables of the voted entries:
http://www.highscore.a2hosted.com/index/

This is coded in django. I managed to get a text entry and a voting form on one page.

**Text Entry:**
The text entry adds a new entry to the database (sqlite3) when the enter key is pressed. a bit of javascript binds the input to the keypress to send to views.py, which uses GET for adding the text and current datetime. No forms were used and the location is reloaded in js.

**Voting Form**
The voting form is POST method, and you have two submit buttons to vote the displayed text up or down. The displayed text is accessed from a 'for loop' in the html. This is updated from views.py as the latest unvoted text when the page is refreshed.

In the vote function in views.py, the name of the up or down button is sent as well as the id of the entry being voted on. The votes add or subtract from the entry's score, saves it, and refreshes the page.

**Physical Install**
My next step is to build a physical install that uses the web architecture. The final install will not be on one page, so there will be a voting station and an entry station. I will be using arcade buttons to make the entry and voting presses.

**Arcade Buttons > Joystick Encoder > Joy2Key Mapper**
I have the arcade buttons wired up to a ZeroDelay joystick encoder, and have Joy2Key running with buttons mapped to 13 (enter) 38 (up arrow) and 40 (down arrow).

All works well with the text entry (joystick button mapped to enter button 13).

Where I run into problems is trying to get keys to work with django forms.
Since the voting uses forms, django expects a mouseclick in a button area. I'm trying to get around that. The closest I have gotten is to put a superfluous text input box in the voting form to capture the key activity.

When the box is active, I can press a button mapped to the up arrow and see some POST feedback in my command prompt (but it's not sending votes yet). If I click on the text entry box, I can press the button mapped to the enter button and have GET feedback in my command prompt and successful text entry.

**So my question is..... without loads of external libraries or fancy Gamepad API coding, is there a tidy way to make django form buttons work from keyboard presses only?** if there needs to be an active box, could this be hidden and fullscreen ? (I've tried it with no luck yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Here's what I did.

In a new voting.html, I had this code to capture the arrow buttons the joystick was mapped to:

```
<div id="Vote" class = "high">
  <div style="text-align: center">
  {% for entry in voting_entry_list %} 
    <li><a href="/entries/{{ entry.id }}/">{{ entry.text }}&nbsp{{ entry.score }}</a></li>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" id="voteid" name='voteid' value="{{ entry.id }}" autofocus value="" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" class = "transparent"/>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#voteid").bind("keydown", function(e) { //input type=id above
                if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                  var text = $("#voteid").val();        
                  var args = {'voteid':text};       
                  $.get("/voteup/", args).done(function(data) {
                    console.log("message: " + data);
                    location.reload();  
                  });
                return false;
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                  var text = $("#voteid").val();        
                  var args = {'voteid':text};       
                  $.get("/votedown/", args).done(function(data) {
                    console.log("message: " + data);
                    location.reload();  
                  });
                return false;
                }       
              });
            });     
          </script>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in views.py, I used GET instead of POST to capture the up or down votes:

```
def voting(request):   
context = {
  'latest_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10], # simple sorting by datetime, latest first, 10 items
  'high_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-score','-pub_date')[:10], # simple sorting by score high to low, 10 items
  'high_entry': Entry.objects.order_by('-score','-pub_date')[:1], # simple sorting by score high to low, 10 items
  'low_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('score','-pub_date')[:10], # simple sorting by score low to high, 10 items
  'voting_entry_list': Entry.objects.unvoted_or_random(), # actually one item, command from extended object manager
}
return render(request, 'entries/voting.html', context); # returns when vote is accessed

def voteup(request):
voting_id = request.GET.get('voteid') # voting id number is brought in as var
if request.method=='GET': #always polling, when get votes, save and redirect to /index to refresh
    v = Entry.objects.get(pk=voting_id) # get by voting id var
    v.score +=1 # add one to score for voteup button
    v.voted=True # set voted boolean to true
    v.save() # explicit save, as is not saved with change above
else:
    pass
return HttpResponse('done') # Only on console 

def votedown(request):
voting_id = request.GET.get('voteid') # voting id number is brought in as var
if request.method=='GET': #always polling, when get votes, save and redirect to /index to refresh
    v = Entry.objects.get(pk=voting_id) # get by voting id var
    v.score -=1 # add one to score for voteup button
    v.voted=True # set voted boolean to true
    v.save() # explicit save, as is not saved with change above
else:
    pass
return HttpResponse('done') # Only on console
```

This seems to avoid any issues with forms and keypresses. Since it is on a separate voting page, the transparent dummy submit button makes that selection active on refresh, as opposed to the text entry box when they were on the same page. I can access the sorted entries from the voting_entry_list, and vote up or down with separate js scripts and views.py requests for each button.

My goal was to do this with basic django and js, not being confident with installing a load of libraries or coding extra gamepad.api states and polling, so job done!.

This works for now as a kludge, but one that seems solid. In the future, I may try to streamline it with switch for the keypresses, and perhaps try to use POST instead of GET if that is a security issue.